# Toeplitz operator on $\tilde{H}^2 (\mathbb{T}^2)$

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Currently, I am reading about Toeplitz operators on $\tilde{H}^2(\mathbb{T})$. Now, I want to know about the properties of Toeplitz operators on $\tilde{H}^2(\mathbb{T}^2)$. The problem is that I can not find suitable literature on this topic.

Please, can somebody post a good reference on this topic?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the related books from here.http://b-ok.org/s/?q=toeplitz+operator&yearFrom=&yearTo=&language=&extension=&t=0

I hope this link is useful.